# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentBottom' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am new in android development...I have an error that is ,No resource identifier found for attribute 'alignParentBottom' in package 'android'.my layout code is as follows

```
            <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/add" />
```

How to solve it?

Comment: clean your project. hope it will fix

Comment: Go to project and select clean, it will fix the problem.

Comment: What is your parent layout?? IS it linear layout or relative?

Comment: Actually , i tried  already.but error is still there.my R.java file also not there.

Comment: It is relative layout

Answer (score 1):

it should be

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true".
```

not

```
android:alignParentBottom="true"
```

and make sure that `Button`'s parent is a `RelativeLayout`

Comment: to Gopal Rao, my parent layout is relative layout

Comment: @NeenuJose111 So still the problem exists?

Comment: ..Yes.the error is existing. i deleted that line of code.(android:layout_alignParentBottom="true").now the error is showing like error: Error parsing XML: duplicate attribute

Answer (score 0):

This attribute is incorrect: android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"

We use @+id to create a new id for a View. To reference an existing View use @id. This may be the cause of your errors.

The correct syntax is: android:layout_below="@id/editText1"